# Run script on a selected file

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, rar, unrar

I'm trying to make script or automate `unrar` to unrar a selected file to a specific folder (hard coded).

I want the following code to be run in terminal by clicking a button in finder or a keyboard shortcut while I have a file selected.

```
unrar e <path_to_selected_file.rar> <hard_coded_path>
```

How can I do this in the best way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of an answer on SuperUser - [How to execute a shell script with selected files/folders in finder?](http://superuser.com/q/154726)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/596271

Answer (score 1):

If your destination path is hardcoded, then I suggest you to use Automator.
First create a Service. Select on top, "get the file" in application "Finder".
Then add only one action : "run an Applescript".

In that action, the default script starts with variable "input". This variable will contains the list of all selected files while you're doing a right click on them in the Finder. Build your script to loop through files of that list, using POXIS function to  convert the finder path (myUser:myfolder:myfile) to shell path (myUser/myfolder/myfile). With this path, use the "do shell script" command to run your "unbar" script.

When saved and tested, you can also define a shortcut key for that Service (in System Preferences).

Here is the script which should be in your Applescript Action :

```
on run {input, parameters}
set Destination to path to desktop folder -- User Desktop by default. can be changed    
set PosixDest to POSIX path of Destination

set SelectedFiles to input
repeat with myFile in SelectedFiles -- loop through each selected file
    set PosixF to POSIX path of myFile -- convert Finder path to Unix path
    try -- try block to handle error during unbar
        do shell script "unrar e " & (quoted form of PosixF) & " " & (quoted form of PosixDest)
    end try
end repeat -- next file

return input
end run
```

This example is running as long as you select compressed file (to accept the unbar command). To be more safe, you should just add a test to your file, to check if it is a file OK for unbar. If not, just do nothing.

Comment: I don't follow on how I'm supposed to use the [input] inside the shell script, and also my path contains spaces and "!" that applescript seems to have a problem with, how do I handle that?